# Short story anthologised in the 1970s where a starship pilot tries to become a colonist

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short story where a starship pilot settles on a colonised planet. When partner is killed by indigenous life which was driven out of town drains by flooding he goes back to being a pilot. Would have been anthologised in the 1970’s.

Editing this with some more story details as I can remember them to help with identification.
•   Starship crewman lands on planet colonised by humans
•   Does not want to return to space as time jumps at each planet disorientating
•   Becomes involved with a woman (marries?)
•   Live in a city on the planet
•   Heavy rainfall floods the city allowing some sort of dangerous animals into the city
•   Woman is killed by one of the creatures
•   Starship crewman goes back to his old job in space

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall anything about the other stories in the anthology?  Or anything about the anthology itself: editor, cover art, etc.?

Comment: "killed by indigenous life" makes me immediately go to Harry Harrison's Deathworld series.

Comment: Thanks but if I could be sure of any of the other stories in the anthology we would not be having this conversation. It was a library book, potentially Gollancz so no recollection of any specific cover art.

Comment: Any feel for which Deathworld?

Comment: You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking about the superb 1966 Roger Zelazny story "[This Moment of the Storm](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53898)"

It can be read at the Internet Archive in its original publication in [F&SF](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v030n06_1966-06_PDF/mode/1up)

It contains the elements of a space traveler who settles down on a planet, loses his lover in a heavy storm, and eventually leaves the planet.

There are creatures driven into the city by the storm and the protagonist fights them, but the protagonist's lover is actually killed by a looter after the storm.

The space travel technology in the story involves "cold sleep" and long duration.

> I was born about five hundred ninety seven years ago on Earth, but I spent about five hundred sixty two of those years sleeping during my long jaunts between the stars.

It's in several anthologies but mostly in the many printings and editions of *The Doors of His Face, The Lamps of His Mouth*. What a great collection that is. Thanks for asking this question and prompting me to pull it off the shelf and read it again.