# Trying to track down a short story from an anthology (probably hardcover) in the 1970s, basic details as far as as I can remember them are below-

Tags: story-identification

- Starship crewman lands on planet colonised by humans
- Does not want to return to space as time jumps at each planet disorientating
- Becomes involved with a woman (marries?)
- Live in a city on the planet
- Heavy rainfall floods the city allowing some sort of dangerous animals into the city
- Woman is killed by one of the creatures
- Starship crewman goes back to his old job in space

Comment: Hi Matt. You asked this last year in [Short story anthologised in the 1970s where a starship pilot tries to become a colonist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275204/short-story-anthologised-in-the-1970s-where-a-starship-pilot-tries-to-become-a-c).

Comment: Please [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/275204/edit) your previous post to add the new details that you've mentioned here.

Comment: Matt, I have an answer for you at the other question.